# Static variables in PHP are different for each user

Tags: php

Static variables in PHP are different for each user that makes a connection to the PHP page.  How come this is so if a static variable is supposed to be... well, static?

That leads me to the second part of this question: is there a way to create a global static variable that is shared across all connections?

Comment: Can you show some code to support your first statement?

Comment: See [static methods and properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) and [static variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static). For shared, global values, I'd look into some kind of in-memory cache like [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)

Comment: Static doesn't mean constant; static just refers to how it's referenced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static variables are only static and available within a specific scope of execution. Once the Apache thread that spawned that instance of PHP is destroyed, that static variable is removed from memory. Since a second user hitting your web server would mean that Apache loads up a new thread, spawning a brand new instance of PHP, which runs within its own scope. Therefore, the static variable defined in the first thread isn't available in the second.

Comment: How about the second part?

Comment: @minitech The second part could be handled by a number of things, the most commonly implemented of which would be a database.